# Class ser port is none if unused in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection, pyserial

I'm writing a class that uses a function, get_serial_port(). If self.ser.write('at\r') isn't called in **init**, then self.ser is None elsewhere in the class. 
(note that the get_serial_port function verifies communication before returning the instance). I assume this has something to do with garbage collection in the Serial class, but I don't understand what's going on. Why is this?

The function get_serial_port checks communication and returns an instance linked to a com port. The init_module() function runs several functions using self.ser.write('command'). It works as is, but I don't like having code in place that I don't understand...

```py
class Device():
    def __init__(self, log = True, com_port=None, imei=None, ser=None, baud_rate=115200):
        if log:
            self.log = True
            self.log = Logger()
            self.log.start_log()
        if ser is None:
            try: 
                self.ser = get_serial_port(baud_rate=baud_rate)
                self.ser.write('at\r')
                print(self.ser.read(1000))
            except:
                print('ERROR: serial port connection failed')
            else:
                self.ser = ser
        self.imei = imei
        self.init_module()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in the code. For one thing, setting log to True does not do anything, as the same instance var is overwritten in the same line. I'm not saying this is exemplary, but would this be a bit more clear? I tried to rewrite it so that it is easier to track state.

Also added some idiomatic conventions (don't test explicitly for None unless really needed)

```py
class Device():
    def __init__(self, log = True, com_port=None, imei=None, ser=None, baud_rate=115200):
        self.log_enabled = log
        self.ser = ser
        self.imei = imei

        if log:
            self.logger = Logger()
            self.logger.start_log()

        if not self.ser:
            try: 
                self.ser = get_serial_port(baud_rate=baud_rate)
                self.ser.write('at\r')
                print(self.ser.read(1000))
            except:
                print('ERROR: serial port connection failed')

        self.init_module()
```

Note that I stored `log` boolean separately to `self.log_enabled`, so that it can be checked in the code if logging is enabled. There are better options though:

- Set log level when running, and instead of disabling logging, set it to `warning` or similar to log only important things
- You could also create another Null logger with interface similar to Logger(), then you would not need to use if every time

But I'd go with log levels, then you can remove the first `if` -- removing conditionals is usually a very good way to simplify code -- and just go with log levels.